# Как сделать вывод данных в одну строку?

Tags: python, subprocess

Как я могу сделать вывод модуля `subprocess` в одну строку - `\n`?

```
ipconfig_res = subprocess.Popen("ipconfig", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in ipconfig_res.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        print(line.decode('cp866'))
```

Этот код выводит все слова в большое количество строк. Помогите перевести все это в одну строку.

Comment: `print("То, что нужно вывести", end='')`. По умолчанию параметр `end` имеет значение `\n`, т.е. перенос строки. Можно заменить его на любой удобный - пробел, пустая строка, запятая и т.д.

Comment: К сожалению для меня это не подходит.. Есть еще идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
ipconfig_res = subprocess.Popen("ipconfig", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
lines = []
for line in ipconfig_res.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        lines.append(line.decode('cp866'))
print('\\n '.join(lines))
```

out:

```
Настройка протокола IP для Windows\n Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet 5:\n DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :\n Локальный IPv6-адрес к ............
```

или

```
ipconfig_res.stdout.read().decode('cp866').replace('\r\n', '\\n')
```